# CorePlot - CPTAnnotation.h not found

Tags: objective-c, core-plot, ios5

I'm trying to use [`CorePlot`](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/) to draw a simple plot.

I'm working from [this tutorial](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-core-plot-in-an-iphone-application), but when I type this in my `ViewController.h`:

```
<CPPlotDataSource>
{
   CPXYGraph *graph;
}
```

I encounter an error: `CPTAnnotation.h file not found`

What might be the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Core Plot class prefix has changed from "CP" to "CPT" since that tutorial was written. If you're using anything later than Core Plot 0.3, you'll need to make the change in your code, too. There are several other needed changes that are discussed in the comments on that post.

Comment: ok, thank you for help, i solved it when i read the comments below and framework is available for my project but i've got new problem. i've got 9 errors about: `"Property attributes 'assign' and 'weak' are mutually exclusive"` (9 times) in files: `CPTAnnotation.h, CPTAxis.h, CPTLayer.h, CPTLayerAnnotation.h, CPTLegendEntry.h, CPTPlotSpace.h` . how can i solve it?

Comment: i resigned from core-plot, s7graphView is simplier. thanks for help.

Comment: When you say "that post," what post are you referring to?

Comment: I was referring to the tutorial linked in the original question.